# How can I connect and communicate between Pis using an Ethernet?

Tags: networking

New to Pi, but want to be able to connect two Pi’s together using an ethernet and communicate with each other.

How would I do this?

Comment: a Raspberry Pi is a computer, similar to a PC or a Mac ... your question is not specific to the RPi ... it is a linux question

Comment: Yes I know they will take ethernet’s but is there any configuring of IP’s needed between one and another?

Comment: maybe yes, maybe no ... have you connected both RPis to your LAN? ... are you able to browse the internet with each one? ...  it seems like you are asking before you even tried anything

Comment: Depends what you mean by "communicate" . If you connect 2 Pi you can ssh although it is easier to use your router.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect them with a simple CAT5 cable (568A to 568A or 568B to 568B, no crossover needed) then assign an IP address on each end of the link it will "just work".

The system will assign an IP address from `169.254.xxx.xxx` automatically by default, but that's a pain as you have to find the new IP address each time you reboot either system. Setting a static IP address is easy.

Use `sudo ip addr add 192.168.137.1 dev eth0` on one RPi and `sudo ip addr add 192.168.137.2 dev eth0` on the other to give them both fixed IP addresses.

Or add these lines in /etc/dhcpcd.conf (on RPi1)

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.137.1/24
static routers=192.168.137.1
```

and these lines on RPi2

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.137.2/24
static routers=192.168.137.2
```

Reboot or restart dhcpcd5 to get those new fixed IP addresses activated.